# GroupBy keys in a json in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a field in my db that is like the json below:

```
{"term_1": {"value": ["100"], "comment": ""}, "term_2": {"value": ["56"], "comment": ""}, "term_3": {"value": ["36"], "comment": "can be null"}, "term_n": {"value": ["8"], "comment":""}}
```

So each row can have this json with term_1 to term_n(can be 1 to several unique terms).Also, the `value` will always be present even when it's `null` but `comment`can not exist sometimes.

**I need this output:(values are random)**

term     times_appeared  average_value
term_1        10             5
term_2        4              6.5
term_n        2              3.0

Is there any way to do this?

I am trying this:

```
WITH dataset (json_val) AS (
    select cast(tags as json) from mytable
)

SELECT term, count (*) times_appeared, avg(value) average_value 
FROM (
        SELECT term,
            reduce( -- use array_sum instead of reduce if presto version/flavour allows it
                cast(
                    json_extract(tags, '$.value') as array(integer)
                ),
                0,
                (x, y)->x + y,
                s->s
            ) value
        FROM dataset
            CROSS JOIN UNNEST (cast(json_val as MAP(varchar, json))) as t(term, tags)
    )
GROUP BY term
ORDER BY term
```

Answer (score 0):

The main trick is to convert json to `MAP(varchar, json)`, unnest it and process accordingly:

```sql
WITH dataset (json_val) AS (
    VALUES (JSON '{"term_1": {"value": ["100"], "comment": ""}, "term_2": {"value": ["56"], "comment": ""}, "term_3": {"value": ["36"], "comment": "can be null"}, "term_n": {"value": ["8"], "comment":null}}' ),
     (JSON '{"term_1": {"value": ["10"]}}')
)

SELECT term, count (*) times_appeared, avg(value) average_value 
FROM (
        SELECT term,
            reduce( -- use array_sum instead of reduce if presto version/flavour allows it
                cast(
                    json_extract(inner_json, '$.value') as array(integer)
                ),
                0,
                (x, y)->x + y,
                s->s
            ) value
        FROM dataset
            CROSS JOIN UNNEST (cast(json_val as MAP(varchar, json))) as t(term, inner_json)
    )
GROUP BY term
ORDER BY term
```

Output:

| term | times_appeared | average_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| term_1 | 2 | 55.0 |
| term_2 | 1 | 56.0 |
| term_3 | 1 | 36.0 |
| term_n | 1 | 8.0 |

Comment: Huge Thanks!  Just one problem now:  How do I change the code to this using all rows of this table using the field where this json is?   I mean, the field is called `tags` and I have 1kk rows in this table. I guess I have to change th first part of your code right?

Comment: i tried `WITH dataset (json_val) AS ( select cast(tags as json) from table)) but didn work.

Comment: @pouchewar `WITH dataset (json_val)` is just test data setup. You can change `FROM dataset` to `FROM YourTableName` in the query, change `json_val` to your actual column name and remove the `WITH` completely (also possibly add cast to json were needed).  _" didn work."_ does not say much. What was the error?

Comment: I updated my question with your code.  The error is: `INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to map(varchar, json). Expected a json object, but got`  but I used a website to check my json and it passed the test as valid

Comment: @pouchewar the one in question is not a valid json - I needed to fix it, it is missing value for last `comment` property.

Comment: it was a typo.   If I run `select cast(tags as json) from table limit 1` works fine.  I don know then what to do :-(

Comment: then only weird thing when I run `select cast(tags as json) from table limit 1`is that the output is a json but witn ` \ `  like this: `"{\"term1\": {\"value\": [\"7\"], \"comment\": \"\"}`

Comment: I now get the count for the terms correctly. I used `json_parse` before the `map`. But I am getting avg as zero...

Comment: @pouchewar was going to suggest `json_parse`. As for avg being zero - need a reproducer with example data.